# How to collect addresses with balance more then 1 ether using dump/snapshot

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

I need to get addresses from some latest block.
I tried geth but is very slow. With parity I got some problems.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires parity to be synced with --fat-db=on

```
parity export state [--no-storage] [--no-code] --min-balance=[WEI] --
max-balance=[WEI] --at=[BLOCK] file.json
```